# PHP : echo not working in infinite while loop

Tags: php

I want to show `$input` from the client using `echo` on the server side.

PHP Server:

```
<?php

$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8000", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
        $input = fread($conn, 1024);
        echo $input;

        fwrite($conn, 'Wait for a while... ' . $input);
        fclose($conn);
    }
    fclose($socket);
}
```

`fwrite()` successfully writes `$input` to client but `echo $input` displaying nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `flush()`:

```
<?php

$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8000", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
   while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
       $input = fread($conn, 1024);
       echo $input;
       ob_flush();
       flush();
       fwrite($conn, 'Wait for a while... ' . $input);
       fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
```

Comment: @AshutoshSurya007 Maybe you have some errors? Try add `ob_flush();` before `flush();`  please

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct, it would have been nice to explain to the user *why* flush is necessary.